# Python: How to catch and handle a user defined exception?

Tags: python, exception

I want to catch and handle a specific Exception and I want all others to be raised.

The exception I want to catch is like:

```
Exception("exception want to catch")
```

The code I tried below doesn't work. In the first code I want the exception to be raise;

```
try:
    raise Exception("exception don't want to catch")
except Exception("exception want to catch"):
    pass
```

But I wouldn't want an exception raise for this code:

```
try:
    raise Exception('exception want to catch')
except Exception('exception want to catch'):
    pass
```

Comment: Sounds like this could be an XY problem to me- else you just need to give more detail one what you are actually trying to do with this.

Comment: I would recommend you to create you own exception derived class and make an except for it and pass it.

Comment: Different types of error (e.g. `ValueError` vs. `TypeError`) or the same type of error with a different message? Did you write the code that raises the error, too?

Comment: Okay, but this isn't my code. I am using a module which throws an Exception('like this').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define (or use preexisting) concrete exception classes instead of relying on the strings:

```
>>> class ExcToCatch(Exception): pass
... 
>>> class ExcToNotCatch(Exception): pass
... 
>>> try:
...     raise ExcToCatch()
... except ExcToCatch:
...     pass
... 
>>> try:
...     raise ExcToNotCatch()
... except ExcToCatch:
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
__main__.ExcToNotCatch
```

Presumably `ExcToCatch` and `ExcToNotCatch` mean something more meaningful, so they should be named appropriately.

---

If you absolutely *must* rely on the strings, you can obtain the string via `str(exception)`:

```
>>> try:
...     raise Exception('some string')
... except Exception as e:
...     print str(e)
... 
some string
```

You can include some logic in the `except` block to re-`raise` `e` when necessary (e.g. when `str(e) != 'exception want to catch'`).

Comment: This is exactly the outcome which I want. But is there no way to do it without making exception classes?

Comment: @WillBeauchamp there are many [built-in exception classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) - there is often one close enough to your use case to use.

Answer (score 1):

If this exception derives from `BaseException` (which it seems like it's actually an instance of `Exception`) you can check the `args` property. The first should be the string you want to handle:

```
try:
  #stuff
catch Exception as ex:
  if ex.args[0] == 'My Exception string':
    #do stuff
  else:
    raise
```

That said, if you have any control over this library, please go and find the author to have him change it. If you do not, my condolences.